# SVG linking rect in different SVG files and animate them

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, hyperlink, scripting

I search everywhere and I didn't understand/found how to do what I want.
I Have 2 svg files who represent somes UML diagrams generated by Visual Paradigm for UML, they have similar objects. For exemple 'FileSource.svg' and 'FileDestination.svg',  both of them have an object 'A' who is on  differents positions for each.

I would like that when you click on 'A' in 'FileSource.svg' that return 'A' in 'FileDestination.svg' with an hightlight  on 'A' to see where it's in the diagram 'FileDestination.svg.

Here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jim987/rJk54/ 
But I don't find how to create 2 files with jsfiddle, so the linking part don't work..

First I tried to link  the similar objects, there is the code for one object in diagram :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd'>
<svg fill-opacity="0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" color-rendering="auto" color-interpolation="auto" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" text-rendering="auto" stroke-linecap="square" width="1267" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-opacity="0" shape-rendering="auto" fill="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-dasharray="none" font-weight="normal" stroke-width="1" height="626" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" font-family="&apos;Dialog&apos;" font-style="normal" stroke-linejoin="miter" font-size="12" stroke-dashoffset="0" image-rendering="auto">
<defs id="genericDefs"/>
<g>
    <defs id="defs1">
        <clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath7">
            <path d="M-7 -7 L101 -7 L101 51 L-7 51 L-7 -7 Z"/>
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath10">
            <path d="M0 0 L90 0 L90 15 L0 15 L0 0 Z"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g font-size="11" transform="translate(1173,2)" fill-opacity="1" fill="rgb(255,192,255)" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" font-family="sans-serif" stroke="rgb(255,192,255)" font-weight="bold" stroke-opacity="1">
        <a xlink:href="FileDestination.svg#A_Object_FileDestination" xlink:title="object definition">
            <rect x="0" width="90" height="40" y="0" clip-path="url(#clipPath7)" stroke="none"/>
        </a>
    </g>
    <g font-size="11" stroke-linecap="butt" transform="translate(1173,2)" fill-opacity="1" fill="black" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" font-family="sans-serif" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke="black" font-weight="bold" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-miterlimit="0">
        <rect fill="none" x="0" width="90" height="40" y="0" clip-path="url(#clipPath7)"/>
    </g>
    <g font-size="11" transform="translate(1173,2)" fill-opacity="1" fill="black" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" font-family="sans-serif" stroke="black" font-weight="bold" stroke-opacity="1">
        <a xlink:title="object def">
            <text x="21" xml:space="preserve" y="12" clip-path="url(#clipPath10)" stroke="none">Object A</text>
        </a>
        <line y2="12" fill="none" x1="21" clip-path="url(#clipPath10)" x2="66" y1="12"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Object A in FileDestination.svg :

```
<g font-size="11" transform="translate(712,44)" fill-opacity="1" fill="rgb(255,192,255)" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" font-family="sans-serif" stroke="rgb(255,192,255)" font-weight="bold" stroke-opacity="1">
    <rect id="A_Object_FileDestination" x="0" width="90" height="40" y="0" clip-path="url(#clipPath13)" stroke="none"/>
</g>
```

The problem is : when I creates this link my rectangle color become black.. do you know why ?

Also is it possible to link my object with the transform defined ? (I saw it in the doc)
 like this : 
    FileDestination.svg#svgView(transform(translate(712,44)))
Because I added the id for each rectangle, when svg files are generate there isn't any ids, just the transforms.

The translate corresponding at the transform of A in FileDestination, but when I tried it, I just have a blank before my diagram..

And Finally, I have no idea, how to do my animation to target the destination of the link. Certainly in JavaScript or with d3.js ? with actionListener ? but how ? because objects are not in the same page. And I do not how to handle the fact that the objects aren't in the same page.

Thanks by advance for yours answers :))

Comment: I would probably include a fiddle to highlight any specific problem.

Comment: Excuse me but I didn't understood, How can I do this ?

Comment: Try and get an example on http://jsfiddle.net/ that highlights the problem. You can paste SVG in the top section. You would need to adjust your links so they load in the relevant other svg files.